# I created a block for fabric 1.18.1 and it doesn't show up in game at all

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I created a block in IntelliJ and ran the client and the game came up with no errors but the block is not there in inventory or with commands.

The idea of the block is to create piles of gold coins that work like pickles where you can place multiple on a block.

Please take a look at my code and help me understand why it won't show up.

Here is my code for the block itself:

```
`package net.runic.runicscurrencymod.block.custom;

import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.object.builder.v1.block.FabricBlockSettings;
import net.minecraft.block.*;
import net.minecraft.entity.ai.pathing.NavigationType;
import net.minecraft.fluid.FluidState;
import net.minecraft.fluid.Fluids;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemPlacementContext;
import net.minecraft.server.world.ServerWorld;
import net.minecraft.state.StateManager;
import net.minecraft.state.property.BooleanProperty;
import net.minecraft.state.property.IntProperty;
import net.minecraft.state.property.Properties;
import net.minecraft.tag.BlockTags;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.util.math.Direction;
import net.minecraft.util.shape.VoxelShape;
import net.minecraft.world.BlockView;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraft.world.WorldAccess;
import net.minecraft.world.WorldView;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
import java.util.Random;

public class GoldCoinPile extends Block {
    public GoldCoinPile(Settings settings) {
        super(settings);
        this.setDefaultState((BlockState)((BlockState)((BlockState)this.stateManager.getDefaultState()).with(PILES, 1)).with(WATERLOGGED, true));
}
    public static final int MAX_PILES = 4;
    public static final IntProperty PILES = net.runic.runicscurrencymod.state.Properties.PILES;
    public static final BooleanProperty WATERLOGGED = Properties.WATERLOGGED;
    protected static final VoxelShape ONE_PILE_SHAPE = Block.createCuboidShape(6.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 6.0, 10.0);
    protected static final VoxelShape TWO_PILES_SHAPE = Block.createCuboidShape(3.0, 0.0, 3.0, 13.0, 6.0, 13.0);
    protected static final VoxelShape THREE_PILES_SHAPE = Block.createCuboidShape(2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 14.0, 6.0, 14.0);
    protected static final VoxelShape FOUR_PILES_SHAPE = Block.createCuboidShape(2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 14.0, 7.0, 14.0);



    @Override
    @Nullable
    public BlockState getPlacementState(ItemPlacementContext ctx) {
        BlockState blockState = ctx.getWorld().getBlockState(ctx.getBlockPos());
        if (blockState.isOf(this)) {
            return (BlockState)blockState.with(PILES, Math.min(4, blockState.get(PILES) + 1));
        }
        FluidState fluidState = ctx.getWorld().getFluidState(ctx.getBlockPos());
        boolean bl = fluidState.getFluid() == Fluids.WATER;
        return (BlockState)super.getPlacementState(ctx).with(WATERLOGGED, bl);
    }

    public static boolean isDry(BlockState state) {
        return state.get(WATERLOGGED) == false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canReplace(BlockState state, ItemPlacementContext context) {
        if (!context.shouldCancelInteraction() && context.getStack().isOf(this.asItem()) && state.get(PILES) < 4) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.canReplace(state, context);
    }

    @Override
    public VoxelShape getOutlineShape(BlockState state, BlockView world, BlockPos pos, ShapeContext context) {
        switch (state.get(PILES)) {
            default: {
                return ONE_PILE_SHAPE;
            }
            case 2: {
                return TWO_PILES_SHAPE;
            }
            case 3: {
                return THREE_PILES_SHAPE;
            }
            case 4: 
        }
        return FOUR_PILES_SHAPE;
    }

    @Override
    public FluidState getFluidState(BlockState state) {
        if (state.get(WATERLOGGED).booleanValue()) {
            return Fluids.WATER.getStill(false);
        }
        return super.getFluidState(state);
    }

    @Override
    protected void appendProperties(StateManager.Builder<Block, BlockState> builder) {
        builder.add(PILES, WATERLOGGED);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean canPathfindThrough(BlockState state, BlockView world, BlockPos pos, NavigationType type) {
        return false;
    }
}
`
```

I created the piles property with a Properties.java and the code inside it is this:

````
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0.0.9 (FabricMC cc05e23f).
 */
package net.runic.runicscurrencymod.state;

import net.minecraft.block.enums.*;
import net.minecraft.state.property.BooleanProperty;
import net.minecraft.state.property.DirectionProperty;
import net.minecraft.state.property.EnumProperty;
import net.minecraft.state.property.IntProperty;
import net.minecraft.util.math.Direction;

public class Properties {

   ``` public static final IntProperty PILES = IntProperty.of(name:"piles",min:1,max:4);
````

And in the mod block file i registered it like this:

```
public static final Block GOLD_COIN_PILE = registerBlock("gold_coin_pile",
            new GoldCoinPile(FabricBlockSettings.of(Material.METAL).strength(6f)), ItemGroup.MISC);
```

In the blockstates folder I have a gold_coin_pile.json that says:

```
{
  "variants": {

    "piles=1": [
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/gold_coin_pile"
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/gold_coin_pile",
        "y": 90
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/gold_coin_pile",
        "y": 180
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/gold_coin_pile",
        "y": 270
      }
    ],

    "piles=2": [
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/two_gold_coin_piles"
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/two_gold_coin_piles",
        "y": 90
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/two_gold_coin_piles",
        "y": 180
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/two_gold_coin_piles",
        "y": 270
      }
    ],

    "piles=3": [
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/three_gold_coin_piles"
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/three_gold_coin_piles",
        "y": 90
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/three_gold_coin_piles",
        "y": 180
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/three_gold_coin_piles",
        "y": 270
      }
    ],

    "piles=4": [
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/four_gold_coin_piles"
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/four_gold_coin_piles",
        "y": 90
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/four_gold_coin_piles",
        "y": 180
      },
      {
        "model": "minecraft:block/four_gold_coin_piles",
        "y": 270
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In the actual blocks folder I have four json files for each of the blockstates but here is the one for just 1 pile (if you need all 4 lmk)

```
{
    "parent": "block/block",
    "textures": {
        "particle": "block/gold_coin_pile",
        "all": "block/gold_coin_pile"
    },
    "elements": [
        {   "from": [ 6, 0, 6 ],
            "to": [ 10, 6, 10 ],
            "faces": {
                "down":  { "uv": [  8, 1,  12, 5 ], "texture": "#all", "cullface": "down" },
                "up":    { "uv": [  4, 1,  8, 5 ], "texture": "#all" },
                "north": { "uv": [ 4, 5, 8, 11 ], "texture": "#all" },
                "south": { "uv": [ 0, 5, 4, 11 ], "texture": "#all" },
                "west":  { "uv": [ 8, 5, 12, 11 ], "texture": "#all" },
                "east":  { "uv": [ 12, 5, 16, 11 ], "texture": "#all" }
            }
        },
        {
            "from": [ 6, 5.95, 6 ],
            "to": [ 10, 5.95, 10 ],
            "faces": {
                "up": {"uv": [  8, 1,  12, 5 ], "texture": "#all"}
            }
        },
        {
            "from": [ 7.5, 5.2, 8 ],
            "to": [ 8.5, 8.7, 8 ],
            "rotation": { "origin": [ 8, 8, 8 ], "axis": "y", "angle": 45, "rescale": true },
            "shade": false,
            "faces": {
                "north": { "uv": [ 1, 0, 3, 5 ], "texture": "#all" },
                "south": { "uv": [ 3, 0, 1, 5 ], "texture": "#all" }
            }
        },
        {
            "from": [ 8, 5.2, 7.5 ],
            "to": [ 8, 8.7, 8.5 ],
            "rotation": { "origin": [ 8, 8, 8 ], "axis": "y", "angle": 45, "rescale": true },
            "shade": false,
            "faces": {
                "west": { "uv": [ 13, 0, 15, 5 ], "texture": "#all" },
                "east": { "uv": [ 15, 0, 13, 5 ], "texture": "#all" }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In the en_us.json lang file I have it like this:

```
"block.runicscurrencymod.gold_coin_pile": "Pile of Gold Coins",
```

And then I have the gold_coin_pile.png file in textures.

I'm not sure what's going on but it won't show up in game at all.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't register the block correctly. Add this line in your initializer class and it should work.

`Registry.register(Registry.BLOCK, new Identifier("example", "example_block"), EXAMPLE_BLOCK);`